# laravel-5.7: file_put_contents

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

i created a project on another pc it was working fine, but when i copy it into another pc and try to open it, thn it says:

> file_put_contents(E:\xampp\htdocs\lweb2\storage\framework/sessions/tQp2cprdDgWqpDLBx52ncxsrn6vRlCpHcZjZXdjI):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

its using the older path where it is created,

```
   file_put_contents(E:\xampp\htdocs\lweb2\storage\framework/sessions/eoFduOIDZQiSf979DOWLulZNJU5oub99k6xqnhkl): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you try `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: Set permissions correctly for `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` directories.

Comment: @Mozammil thnx a lot bro and one thing more,,, in another project i hv cleared the config or view, but during clearing cache it says:  "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions." can u plz tell me the solution of this

Comment: Just feels like a permissions issue. Typically those folders need to be `chmod 777`.

Comment: @Mozammil using windows

Answer (score 1):

From you question and comments it seems you need to delete `public/bootstrap/cache/config.php`

And then run `php artisan config:cache`